# Existence of a complex polynomial with given zeros and critical points?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, lagrange-interpolation

Suppose we are given two families of complex numbers (need not to be distinct) $z_1, z_2, \cdots, z_n$ and $w_1, w_2, \cdots, w_{n-1}$ such that

1. the second family lies in the convex hull of first family and
2. both families have the same center of mass.

   > Now, can we find a polynomial $P$ of degree $n$ that has first family as its collection of zeros and second family as its collection of critical points (counting with multiplicities) ?

[Hermite interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation) gives a polynomial of degree $2n-1$ with these properties introducing new zeros and critical points, but I hope conditions 1. and 2. are enough to guarantee the existence of such a polynomial of degree $n.$ If not, what additional conditions do we need to impose of those two families?

Comment: You need more conditions. Consider the case where $n>2$ is even, half of the $z_k$ are 0, half are 2, and the $w_k$ are all in $(0,2)$ and evenly spaced around 1.

Comment: The point is that once you fix $n$ zeros,  you determine the polynomial up to a multiplicative constant, you have absolutely no leeway on the location of the critical points.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: Thank you very much for your explanation.